# Color-slicing transformations that detect green wood sorrel leaves within an RGB cube

Tags: image-processing, image

Color-slicing transformations that detect green wood sorrel leaves within an RGB cube.
[image]

Comment: This post is at risk of being closed because it does not include a question. Please state the question, and explain all relevant details. Include any code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeQfj.jpg/qeQfj.jpg"];

ImageApply[If[#[[2]] >= Max[#], #, {0, 0, 0}] &, img]
```

[image]

Alternatively, remove red and blue channels if green channel value is the maximum of the three channel values:

```
ImageApply[If[#[[2]] >= Max[#], #[[2]] {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}] &, img]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the transformation you are looking for but Mathematica has a `ColorsNear` function:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeQfj.jpg/qeQfj.jpg"]
ColorDetect[img, ColorsNear[Darker@Green]]
```

[image]